# Improving Training accuracy of LSTM in Keras for ratings prediction given reviews

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm, accuracy

I'm new to Deep Learning and NLP. I found a dataset online which has reviews of different companies and their corresponding ratings from 1 to 5. I encoded the labels, then removed some basic stop words from the text, and tokenized it all using Keras. My model, however, is not performing well at all. Training accuracy starts off at 30% and only goes up to 60%. Validation accuracy also starts off low, at around 35%, and ends at 30%. What do I do to improve the performance?

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 20, input_length=150),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(40, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(padded, train_label1, epochs=10, batch_size=45 ,validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: try word2vec to extract vectors from text and then feed them into ANN